# change height of images on specific resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I have a set of columns which contain some images.

When the user is viewing them below 480px I want to change the height of the images without losing their aspect ratio.

Here's the markup:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="project no-padding col-xs-12">

      <a href="#">
          <figure>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="image.jpg">
          </figure>

      </a>

   </div>
   </div>
   ...
```

I've tried using this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-min) {

.project img { height:200px;}

}
```

The problem with this is that is stretching the image to that height and it doesn't look good at at all.

Is there any workaround to make this with CSS ? If not, is there any JS plugin which can help me doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the class ".image-responsive"?

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

From http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: I have already added the class "img-responvie" but I forgot to add it here. This is not helping me, because the image is resized at 60px height and I want it to be bigger

Comment: Won't that break aspect ratio?

Comment: It will break, that's why I was asking for a method to make the image bigger without breaking the aspect ratio. I think it can be possible to do this, for example serving another image when the resolution is below 480px.

Comment: Well you can't, hence the definition of aspect ratio. Unless I am misunderstanding your problem, you cannot resize just the height without resizing the width AND keeping the aspect ratio the same.